# GtkEntryCompletion additional source

Tags: c, gtk

I want GtkEntryCompletion to get data from additional source (function or another model, no matter) when there's no match in models data. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a custom class that implements the `GtkTreeModel` interface, and retrieves data preferentially from one model and then another if not found.

Comment: hmmmm, didn't think about that. thought to reimplement GtkEntryCompletion (long live Open Source Software! just copy/paste and rename :)), but this solution looks much better